# How to handle GCM from an Android service?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-service

I would like to do (this for example):
1.- GCM arrives
2.- Upload some data to my server from a service running in the background (I don't wanna show any alerts or play any sounds when GCM arrives), perhaps upload the device current location to a server.

I want to do this from Phonegap so I guess I'm going to write a plugin or find a plugin that communicates a service with the javascript source. I don't need Phonegap to receive any kind of messages from the service, but it's the service itself that is going to upload the data that I need. In other words, I'm gonna use Phonegap as UI and start the service that will do all the work. I also need the service to start whenever the user turns pn his/her phone (I guess that comes from service configuration) but I think that the user will have to launch the app at least once (which I think its normal, right?).

My problem right now is that I don't know how to tell my service to do 'something' when a GCM arrives.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple , whenever you recieve a GCM message in your service in

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(final Context arg0, final Intent arg1) {
    String arr=arg1.getStringExtra("message");
    arr2=arr.split("-");

    Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       h.post(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(arg0, arr2[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               if(arr2[0]=="desired value"){
               //launch a method in your service that post data to your server using requests
                  }
    }         
        });
}
```

Now declare a method in ayour service which gathers all the location data  and post it to your server, call that method in void run().

I hope this solution might help you out.

Comment: How do you know what kind of message has just arrived? Sorry, but I'm new to native Android.

Comment: See your server at the backend will run a php script which will send data in form of key value pair. So accordingly you can set a key and assign a value to it for example                                          in above code I am using getStringExtra("message") --- here message is a key which I am going to extract from the response.               You can also fetch multiple keys depending upon the type of type of script running at your backend.

Comment: The response is in form of array which consist of key value pairs ,JSON format.

Comment: Is that gonna work with the GCM? Btw, I'm using a Ruby script to send the GCM.

Comment: See I don't have any idea about ruby , but just use this concept of key value pairs to get the message. Your script should have a capability to generate response in JSON consisting of an array with key-value pairs.